# Can't change indicator colour for FragmentTabHost tabs

Tags: android, tabs, styles, fragment-tab-host

I would like to implement a custom FragmentTabHost in my app. Documentation is limited on this subject, and I am unable to get it to work with my custom indicator drawables (green), they won't show up under the tab buttons.

I get only the default blue indicator. What can be wrong?
Thanks.

```
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Fidis", 
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_text_selector)),
                OffersFragmentActivity.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Locatii", 
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_text_selector)),
                PlacesFragmentActivity.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Harta", 
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_text_selector)),
                MapFragmentActivity.class, null);

        if(isFacebookLoggedIn()){
            System.out.println("We are logged in!");
        } else {
            showLogin();
        }

    }
...
```

tab_text_selector.xml

```
<!-- AOSP copyright notice can be found at the above link -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a problem like this and i solved it with this code statement :

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selected);
```

Good luck!